# Selecting dictionary items by key efficiently in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

suppose I have a dictionary whose keys are strings. How can I efficiently make a new dictionary from that which contains only the keys present in some list?

for example:

```
# a dictionary mapping strings to stuff
mydict = {'quux': ...,
          'bar': ...,
          'foo': ...}

# list of keys to be selected from mydict
keys_to_select = ['foo', 'bar', ...]
```

The way I came up with is:

```
filtered_mydict = [mydict[k] for k in mydict.keys() \ 
                   if k in keys_to_select]
```

but I think this is highly inefficient because: (1) it requires enumerating the keys with keys(), (2) it requires looking up k in keys_to_select each time.  at least one of these can be avoided, I would think.  any ideas?  I can use scipy/numpy too if needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
dict((k, mydict[k]) for k in keys_to_select)
```

if you know all the keys to select are also keys in `mydict`; if that's not the case,

```
dict((k, mydict[k]) for k in keys_to_select if k in mydict)
```

Comment: When using "if k in mydict" like this, does Python perform a has_key type lookup, or does it convert the keys into a list/iterable and loop over them? If it's the latter, " if mydict.has_key(k)" might be more efficient, no? (Haven't found any documentation to clarify, either way, yet. Google skills failed me).

Comment: To answer my own question, using "k in dict" is identical to using "dict.has_key(k)" according to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/

Comment: @pycruft, yep, and, as `timeit` cqn confirm (`python -mtimeit -s'd=dict.fromkeys(range(99))' '23 in d'` etc), `in` is, in fact, about twice as fast as `has_key` (saves a named-attribute lookup each time, which is about the same operation as a dict loolup). There is never any reason to use `has_key` any more, and it's been removed from Python 3.